# how to make predefined tags/code in html or css

Tags: css, html

Let's say I have this html code:

```
<h1>My website</h1>
<p>Welcome to my website</p>
```

Let's say that I want to put that on pretty much every page of my website without copy and pasting the same thing every time. How would I do that?

I'm also open to doing this in javascript but would prefer html or css.

Comment: You should use server-side code to set a layout or inclusion.

Comment: You need server side code for this (PHP, ASP, Java etc.)

Comment: [so] is not a tutorial website. Figure it out how to do this and then get back when you have a real programming question.

Comment: Frontend templating such as handlebars allows you to  write out your layouts and other partial templates which can either be compiled with grunt before you deploy or compile html on the fly with JS http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score -4):

One way to do this would be to use and iframe tag. It allows you to set the source just like an image or an href and can easily implement things like headers without copying and pasting code.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: *one of* the (arguably-not) worst resources for learning programming (yes still at this (2017) day) - Even if many articles are correct, there are still so many nuances among those pages that referencing w3schools is becoming a fun-to-downvote process, specially if the whole answer is based on plain linking. - BTW iframes are BAD if you don't know how to handle them properly - like i.e: using *heavy* JS and messaging systems to make them responsive - either way - templating is not (and ever was) job for iframes.